# Is $\Bbb R$ the soberification of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I'm a beginner.

I read about soberification of topological space and thought that if I soberificate $\mathbb{Q}$, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the neighbourhood filter of $x$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ corresponds to $x$, so the soberification coincides with $\mathbb{R}$. Is this true?

Comment: I foresee a deluge of stars.

Comment: After reading this thread I feel like I could use a little "soberification" myself . . . Cheers!

Comment: Has it anything to do with drunk people having no "filter"? Is this real life?

Comment: @Jp McCarthy:  Real life?  You're kidding, of course!  This here is math.stackexchange!  Not Kansas anymore, either!

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72217/sober-except-not-t-0#comment182979_72217

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is a Hausdorff space. Every Hausdorff space is sober, so its soberification is just itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no neighborhood filter in $\mathbb{Q}$ of $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, at least not one satisfying the correct axioms.

In $\mathbb{Q}$, we have $(x-1,x+1) = (x-1,x)\cup(x,x+1)$.

So the filter of open sets containing $x$ cannot be prime, and should be illegal in whatever source you're using.